# jQuery button click + spring mvc navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

So my problem in short: I have some html page with a button. When the button is clicked, I would like to move to another page. Looks pretty simple, but I can't figure it out.

So, my button handling logic looks like this:

```
$("#go").click(function() {
            var source = $("#dropdown").text();
            $.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url : "mainpage.html",
                data: {provider: source}
            });
        })
```

Now my controller looks like this:

```
   @Controller
    public class MainController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView hello() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("index");
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/mainpage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String goToMainPage(@RequestParam("provider") String provider) {
        System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" + provider.trim());
        return "empty";
    }
}
```

So the story starts on the page associated with `/hello` (=`index.jsp`). The page is found, displayed, everything is all right. However, when I click y button, I can see the bunch of '@' signs printed out, but the page for /hello (`index.jsp`) is displayed again instead of the one for `/mainpage` (which should be `empty.jsp` the file is right there next to the other).

I also tried to return a `ModelAndView`, but that did not help. I tried to split this controller into two, but it did not help. I tried to use POST instead of GET, you know what happened...

This may be a stupid question, but I'm completely new to Spring MVC.

Comment: Why are you doing it via ajax? If you are navigating from one page to another, just do a GET or POST to the url with the required param.

Comment: Somewhere I read that $.post is just a shorthand for $.ajax(..."POST"...); I tried using a simple post/get, but that does not solve my problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I figured it out.
I changed my jQuery function to this:

```
    $("#go").click(function() {
        var source = $("#dropdown").text();
        window.location.href='/mainpage?provider='+source;
    });
```

and controller method to GET.
This also goes through the MVC controller and correctly fetches the value for provider.

Anyways, please let me know if there's a better way to do this.